# Representing graph as a n dimensional binary vector

Tags: graph-theory

The author in this paper 
http://www.di.ens.fr/~shervashidze/papers/SISO08lrgc.pdf,

on pg 2, first para, top left
the author states that

In graph classification the goal is to learn a decision rule from training examples
{${G_{i},y_{i}}$} where $i$=1,  $G_{i}$ is a graph and $y_{i}$ ∈ {${−1, +1}$} is the corresponding class label. Let $S$ be the set of all subgraphs that occur in
at least one training example. Then any graph $G_{i}$ can be represented as a $|S|$ dimensional binary vector $x_{i}$ where $x_{is} = I(s ⊆ G_{i}), ∀s ∈ S,$

I am not understanding how a graph $G_{i}$ can be represented as a $|S|$ dimensional binary vector $x_{i}$, i was wondering if you anybody can explain this with an example ?